# Extract digits using sed with /s

Tags: sed, match

I want to extract the value with op/s

pgmap 512 pgs: 512 active+clean; 1.39TiB data, 4.08TiB used, 1.15TiB / 5.24TiB avail; 4.43MiB/s wr, 46op/s

```
pginfo="pgmap 512 pgs: 512 active+clean; 1.39TiB data, 4.08TiB used, 1.15TiB / 5.24TiB avail; 4.43MiB/s wr, 46op/s"
echo $pginfo | sed -n '/pgmap/s/.* \([0-9]*\) op\/s.*/\1/p'
```

But it does not return anything. Any help pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is looking for a space after the digits but there isn't one.

Also you should quote the echoed variable to prevent it being mangled.

```
echo "$pginfo" | sed -n '/pgmap/s/.* \([0-9][0-9]*\)op\/s.*/\1/p'
```

Comment: That was it the space, It works with this expression too now echo $pginfo | sed -n '/pgmap/s/.* \([0-9]*\)op\/s.*/\1/p'